# Are indefinite integrals of "equivalent" functions always equal?

Tags: calculus, integration, soft-question, indefinite-integrals

How is it possible to prove that the indefinite integrals of "equivalent" functions that cannot be defined at a particular point are equal to each other?

For example,

> $$\int\dfrac {x^2}{x}dx=\int xdx $$
>
> Or,
>
> $$\int\dfrac {(x+1)^2}{x+1}dx=\int (x+1)dx $$

Obviously, the function $f(x)=\dfrac{x^2}{x}$ is not defined at the point $x = 0$, but $f(x)=x$ is defined  and likewise, the function $f(x)=\dfrac {(x+1)^2}{x+1}$ is not defined at the point $x = -1$, but $f(x)=x+1$ is defined.

How can I prove that, the indefinite integrals of these functions must be equal?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

When you are solving the indefinite integral you are looking for primitive functions (of the sub-integral function) in some interval $I$. You need to have an idea up-front what this interval is.

Now... if this interval includes the point(s) -1/0 the sub-integral function is not defined at that point, so really it makes no sense to look for a primitive function at that point (for one or both of the functions). You see if a function is not defined at a given point, it has no primitive too.

If on the other hand the interval does not include the point(s) -1/0, then of course you can cancel the sub-integral function/fraction and solve. So then the primitive function is if of course the same (plus some constant $C$).

So in general the two indefinite integrals are not quite the same.